# Как создать двумерный динамический массив

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Как создать двумерный динамический массив 7 на 7. Пример кода можете написать пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int **matrix = new int*[7];
    for(int i = 0;i<7;i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[7];
    }
```

Вот. Все просто и легко.